# symfony LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle bad credential

Tags: api, symfony, bundle, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I want to integrate LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle of symfony with fosUserBundle , I've follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation) but always I receive 401 bad credentials error .

here is my config.yml file  :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    translator: ~
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

    serializer:
        enabled: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Collaborator
    from_email:
        address: sahnoun.mabrouk@gmail.com
        sender_name: sahnoun MABROUK

# Nelmio CORS Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false


fos_rest:
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
            - { path: '^/login', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: 'html' }
            - { path: '^/register', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: 'html' }
            - { path: '^/resetting', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: 'html' }

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

security.yml :

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/
            logout: true
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout: true
            anonymous: true
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and i've added api_login_check:
`path: /api/login_check` to the route file.

I've read all issues related to this error but nothing work for me.

can any one help me please

Comment: can you please provide us two additional informations:
* how do you make the http calls?
* how did you integrate the success handler?

Comment: I've just configure the bundle and test  the bundle functionality as the documentation said by the curl cmd  : curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=admin -d _password=admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved ! just make fos_userbundle as first provider to check credentials from database

```
security:

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
         id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the respective providers for each route, take a look [here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Tests/Functional/app/config/security_lexik_jwt.yml).

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login:
            ...
            provider: in_memory
            ...

        api:
            ...
            provider: jwt
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but not working also, it return a html response looking like the code of the index page of symfony project !

Comment: solved ! I have just  make fos_userbundle as first provider to check credentials from database